# ERROR: Failed to deserialize user out of session

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, express, passport

Estoy obteniendo el error *Error: Failed to deserialize user out of session* al intentar iniciar sesión mediante passport, deduciendo que el error se encuentre en la función deserializeUser, pero al compararlo con otros proyectos, o bien en la misma documentación, tengo exactamente lo mismo, así que desconozco el si existe algún error. Este es el código del archivo de configuración passport:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const pool = require('../settings/db');
const bcrypt = require('./bcrypt');


const initPassport = () => passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({

    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password',
    //passReqToCallback: true


}, async (username, password, done) => {


    console.log(`Username: ${username}`);
    console.log(`Password: ${password}`);

    const sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?';
    await pool.query(sql, [username], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {

            if (result.length > 0) {
                const user = result[0];
                const validPassword = bcrypt.matchPass(password, user.password);

                if (validPassword) {
                    console.log('Contraseña valida');
                    return done(null, user);
                } else {
                    console.log('Contraseña invalida');
                    return done(null, false);
                }

            } else {
                console.log('La consulta está vacía');
                return done(null, false);
            }
        }
    });



}));


passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    return done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    try {
        const user = pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [id]);
        return done(null, user[0]);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return done(err);
    }

});

module.exports = initPassport;
```

La consulta que se encuentra dentro de initPassport, para comprobar si existe un usuario que coincida con la información recibida desde el formulario me devuelve un objeto que figura en consoloa como RowDataPocket, ya que si intento guardar la consulta en una variable, sin usar result, me la retorna vacía, aún sabiendo que coinciden ambos datos, los del formulario y los de la base de datos.

Dejo también el código relacionado con passport y la base de datos, así como las sesiones, alojado en el archivo index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const path = require('path');
const hbs = require('express-handlebars');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const router = require('./routes/index');
const authentication_routes = require('./routes/auhtentication');
const passport = require('passport');
const session = require('express-session');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const pool = require('./settings/db');
const MYSQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);

dotenv.config()
const app = express();


//*SETTINGS
app.set('port', process.env.APP_PORT);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('.hbs', hbs({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    layoutsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'layout'),
    partialsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'partials'),
    extname: '.hbs'
}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

//*MIDDLEWARE
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(cookieParser(process.env.APP_SECRET));

app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.APP_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MYSQLStore({
        database: process.env.DB_NAME,
        user: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    })
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


//*Variables globales
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    app.locals.user = req.user;
    next();
});

//*STATIC FILES
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//*ROUTES
app.use(router);
app.use(authentication_routes);

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('Server on port: ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Espero cualquier consejo o ayuda. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCIONADO: Modifiqué la consulta de la función deserializeUser del mismo modo que está en initPassport:

```
    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [id], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {

            if (result.length > 0) {
                console.log('Hay algo en la consulta :D');
                return done(null, result[0]);
            } else {
                console.log('La consulta está vacía');
                return done(null, false);
            }

        }
    });
});
```